# How to write a javascript button which contains data?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

How do you create a javascript button to take the information from the form to the php sql:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name" /></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" class="number"/></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Location " name="location" class="location"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Booking" />
 </form>

?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$location = $_GET['location'];

$con = mysql_connect(".....",".....",".....");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

("chanh", $con);
$sql ="INSERT INTO book (name, number, location,timestamp)
VALUES ('$name', '$number','$location',NOW())"; 

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added"

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am just a rookie! Thanks

Comment: add a button, then use onclick="document.forms[0].submit()"

Comment: Your form needs both action and method attributes if you want it to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify where you form will be submitted

```
<form action="submit.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="name" /></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="number" class="number"/></br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Location " name="location" class="location"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Booking" />
 </form>
```

Javascript is only needed here if you want to perform some sort of validation

**NOTE**

Avoid adding variables directly to your query, you will be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Here is what you can do:

```
$con = mysql_connect(".....",".....",".....");
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['number']);
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['location']);
```

Answer (score 0):

create an , then set that when the button is clicked, the form is submitted. ie

```
but = document.getElementById('clickButton');
formToSubmit = document.getElementById('myForm');

but.onclick = function(){
    formToSubmit.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to submit a form.  It looks like you're just missing the `<` from `<?php` for now.

You could explicitly specify the action and method on the form HTML element, but if you don't it's a GET request and it will submit to the current URL (Web address).

Really, if you're doing something other than fetching data (like a search), your form should be using a HTTP POST, not a GET.  For more understanding of why this kind of thing matters, see [What should every programmer know about web development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development). However, that is a very big topic!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to postback the form, in other words, set an action on the form as in:

```
<form id="mainForm" action="process.php" method="post">..
```

And add an `onclick` handler on the button as follows:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Add Booking" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();" />
```

However, not that I set the method to `post`; this will require your PHP code to change to:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
```

Using POST in this case may not be necessary but you need to be aware that using GET will encode the form parameters in the URL as in `process.php?name=value&numner=value...` and some of this information may be sensitive and therefore, desirable to be submitted to the server in the body of the HTTP request as opposed to transmitted encoded in the URL.